# Is there a way to get a collection in a random order?

Tags: morphia

Is it possible to get the full collection of documents in a random order? Or just a random sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation framework's [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/).  The Morphia API to access that is [here](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.2/javadoc/dev/morphia/aggregation/experimental/Aggregation.html#sample(long)).